# Previous user data still visible after logging out and signing in as a new user in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to implement the sign out functionality in my application. It works okay. However, when I sign out and log in as another user. I can still see the old user information. How can I erase the current user data on sign out so that when I log in as another user the information of the previous user is not visible. I will attach my sign out code for reference. if more info is needed please let me know.

```
 @objc private func LogOutButtonTapped() {
        
        
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out", message: "Are you sure, you want to log out?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                            style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
                                                
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: .destructive,
                              handler: { [weak self] _ in
                        
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                            return
                            }
                    
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "email")
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "name")
                 
                                
                                
            do {
                    try Auth.auth().signOut()
                    let vc = LoginViewController()
                    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                    nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    strongSelf.present(nav, animated: true)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Failed to log out")
                    }
            }))
            present(actionSheet, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: What data do you still see?  Where?  You need to clear whatever data you are storing when you log out.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, so I have a profile view controller where I can see user profile picture and then his name and email. When the new user log in I cannot  see the updated name and email. Also from chat view the chats of old users are also present. It works fine if I completely restart the app than simple logout

Answer (score 0):

I have change your code on logout action block. You will have to remove object from user default on logout

```
    @objc private func LogOutButtonTapped() {
    
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out", message: "Are you sure, you want to log out?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                        style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    
    
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: .destructive,
                                        handler: { [weak self] _ in
                                            
                                            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                                return
                                            }
                                            
                                            let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
                                            do {
                                                try firebaseAuth.signOut()
                                            } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                                                print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
                                            }
                                            **remove object on logout click**
                                            USER_DEFAULT.removeObject(forKey: "email") // remove email

                                                let vc = LoginViewController()
                                                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                                                nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                                                strongSelf.present(nav, animated: true)
                                           

                                        }))
    present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sid_patel_1211 This does not improve the situation. I can still see the same problem. It seems as if with the logout I just changed the view controller and nothing else was done. Is there some way through which during the logout I can completely reset the app to it's original state? The issue is not visible if I restart the app

Comment: could you provide me whole code for better understating or GitHub link where I can see your code?

Comment: https://github.com/mzeshiwaheed/ChatAppLearning
here is the GitHub link to the code. It is not a complete set but has the main controllers. I think you'd be interested in the LogIn View controller and then the profile view controller where I perform the logout operation. Thanks @sid_patel_1211

Comment: I have changed code again. You do not sign out user on logout click so I add sing out code please check

Comment: Thanks @sid_patel_1211, for your time on this. Only the profile picture of the new user is updated, name and email remains the same, perhaps the sign out is okay but some other issue is happening

Answer (score 0):

I think the concern lies in your Signin function.

It is useful to remove the UserDefault values as pointed out in the first answer upon logout. But it is also a great idea to save new objects to the UserDefault upon signin, and to read these values on the User Profile View Controller.

Upon signin, fetch the User data using your preferred login method (Email login, FB / Google login, etc.), and save each detail on UserDefaults.

For example:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set("RandomUserName", forKey: "username")
defaults.set("someone@email.com", forKey: "email")
```

After which, upon segue to the User Profile VC (or whatever View Controller you are using to show the User details), read and display these values:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let username = defaults.object(forKey: "username") as? String
let email = defaults.object(forKey: "email") as? String
```

Update:

I checked the code on [GitHub](http://github.com/mzeshiwaheed/ChatAppLearning) and saw that it uses Firebase Database for the content of the chats / conversations. The code itself has the function to refetch for the conversations upon opening the Conversations VC depending on the user's email. What happens was that, because the email of the old user stays even after logout, thus, also the chat contents.
The App may be "restarted" if the correct email (of the new user) is saved  upon signin and called upon opening the Conversations VC, so the 'correct' conversation content will be fetched.

Update:

Try adding some delay before showing the next VC (untested):

```
@objc private func LogOutButtonTapped() {
    
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out", message: "Are you sure, you want to log out?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: .destructive, handler: { [weak self] _ in
    
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
             
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        
        // Remove UserDefaults
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "email")
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "name")
        defaults.synchronize()

        // Add some delay for the Firebase to perform logout function first before showing the VC
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(5000)) {
            let vc = LoginViewController()
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            strongSelf.present(nav, animated: true) }
    
    } catch { print("Failed to log out")
    
    }}))
        present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    } }
```

Comment: I think I am already doing that at Log In and then displaying these values at profile VC, the problem is that they are not refreshed after logout

Comment: I am not sure why the current user is not signed out using the Firebase Auth. The app content is only updated after restart and I am expecting it to happen after log out. I am also new to swift coding so I am lost

Comment: "Not refreshed after logout" - i believe you have something like a "fetch function" to display your saved User Details. Where do you put that code? It's often found in the `viewDidLoad()`, but you can try putting that code in the `viewWillAppear()` of your Profile VC, so that it will be called upon segue to that ViewController.

Comment: using view will appear in conversation controller at least fixes the updating of the chats for the new user, now I need to figure the user profile info update in profile vc

Comment: Regarding the "current user is not signed out using the Firebase Auth", the concern is now on your Firebase logout snippet. Anyway, i updated my answer. Pls check if it resolves anything :)

Comment: I also tried moving the deletion of UserDefaults inside the `do{}` function.

Comment: tried that does not work, I am now wondering whether the tableview is holding to data and there is a way to clear it before logout?

Comment: If that's the case, then we may need to see your Chat VC codes. Do you use tableview.reloadData()?

Comment: This code is in profile vc which is available in the GitHub link I shared. github.com/mzeshiwaheed/ChatAppLearning. I set a break point and I can see that before tableview load the data it reads the new user data from LogIn VC but is not updated and using tableview.reloadData() results in empty cells for tableview